# Problema con el despliegue de las replicas en Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose

tengo un servicio desplegado empleando docker-compose v2 y ando estudiando Docker swarm para reforzar el servicio.

Por lo que el día de ayer, al realizar la parte 3 de la introducción de Docker swarm (https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/), se estableció el servicio de ejemplo con 5 replicas, donde el único inconveniente que tuve fue que el acceso al servicio estaba limitado únicamente a solicitudes empleando Curl, por lo que en el navegador no funcionó.

En base a esto, busqué modificar el archivo de tal manera que me permitiera acceder desde el navegador, sin embargo como consecuencia de esto, no logro que se ejecute mas de una replica a la vez. Tengo entendido que la función de las replicas es el balancear la carga de los servicios y sustituirlos en caso de error.

Serian tan amables de explicarme si existe algún error en el docker-compose.yml expuesto o simplemente en la interpretación de los conceptos.

De antemano agradezco cualquier intervención...

[image: docker-compose]

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo, quieres hacer un curl al contenedor que despliegas en Docker Swarm.
Fijate que cuando haces un **docker service ls** no te aparece ningun puerto en la columna PORTS. Y deberia indicarte en que puerto esta escuchando.

Esta es una de las salidas de mi  Docker Swarm.

```
    sudo docker service ls 
    ID                  NAME                       MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                                              PORTS 

bf26aqknekcd        hcel-mw_hcel               replicated        1/1                 registry.hsap.sacyl.es:5000/hcel-mw:devel         *:30013->80/tcp
```

El puerto lo indico de la siguiente manera en el Docker compose (v3)

```
services:
  front:
    image: registry.hsap.sacyl.es:5000/intranet_front:devel
    ports:
      - "80"
```